# Enviar solicitação POST para PHP através do Xamarin

Tags: c#, mobile, post, xamarin

Estou precisando enviar uma solicitação em `POST` para um arquivo php através deste aplicativo. 
Este código funcionou corretamente no **Windows Forms**, porém no **Xamarin** não tá funcionando...

```
public void testar()
        {
            try
            {
                string nome = txtName.Text;

                string URL = "http://www.italker.com.br/acoes/testphpcsharp.php/";
                WebClient webclient = new WebClient();

                NameValueCollection formData = new NameValueCollection();

                formData["nome"] = nome;

                string responsefromserver = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(webclient.UploadValues(URL, "POST", formData));
                webclient.Dispose();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                    alertErrorShow(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Aqui está a mensagem de erro retornada.

[image: Mensagem de erro retornada pelo Applicativo]

Como envio uma solicitação POST para um arquivo php através do Xamarin C#? Se alguém puder me ajudar nisso, fico muito grato!

Obs: Eu já testei no windows forms e funcionou sem nenhum problema, com este mesmo arquivo que está no nosso servidor.

---

Tentei trocar por [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx), continua funcionando no Windows Forms, porém pelo xamarin apenas não funciona, sem erro sem nada... Será que fiz algo errado?

```
 public void testar()
        {
            try
            {
                string nome = txtName.Text;

                string URL = "http://www.italker.com.br/acoes/testphpcsharp.php/";
                var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("nome", nome)
                });

                var myHttpClient = new HttpClient();
                var response = myHttpClient.PostAsync(URL, formContent);
                alertShow(response.ToString(), true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                alertShow(ex.ToString(), false);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Oi @Joao, tenta usar o [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) ao invés do WebClient..

Comment: Como eu faria usando o HttpClient?

Comment: Eu tentei aqui trocar mas novamente, no windows forms foi de boa, e no xamarin ainda tá dando errado.

Comment: O método `PostAsync`é assíncrono, logo, o método `void testar()` deveria ser `async  void testar()` então chamar o método assíncrono da seguinte forma: `await myHttpClient.PostAsync(URL, formContent)` @JoãoPedro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O método `PostAsync` é assíncrono, logo, o método void testar() deveria ser `async void testar()` então chamar o método assíncrono da seguinte forma: `await myHttpClient.PostAsync(URL, formContent)`

> Veja como ficaria no exemplo do código abaixo:

```
public async void testar()
{
    try
    {
        string nome = txtName.Text;

        string URL = "http://www.italker.com.br/acoes/testphpcsharp.php/";
        var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("nome", nome)
        });

        var myHttpClient = new HttpClient();
        var response = await myHttpClient.PostAsync(URL, formContent);
        alertShow(response.ToString(), true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        alertShow(ex.ToString(), false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, porém agora está retornando um erro de NameResolutionFailure aparentemente no AsyncResult, existe alguma maneira especial de chamar um método assíncrono? @rubStackOverflow

Comment: Lendo sobre o erro informado parece ser um problema difícil de tratar, teste o seguinte `1 verifique se o app tem permissão para usar internet` `2 desabilite o wifi e teste pela rede móvel` `3 Faça uma segunda tentativa de envio na sequencia com uma pequena pausa de 1 segundo` `4 Teste com o IP do servidor http://192.x.x.x/acoes/testphpcsharp.php/` @JoãoPedro

Comment: O app já está com acesso a internet, eu tenstei tanto no emulador, 
quanto no celular (4g e wifi), e ainda tá dando o mesmo problema...
http://i.imgur.com/1BJvg5l.png

Comment: Tentou também os passos 3 e 4? `3 Faça uma segunda tentativa de envio na sequencia com uma pequena pausa de 1 segundo` `4 Teste com o IP do servidor http://192.x.x.x/acoes/testphpcsharp.php/`

Comment: Qual versão do android está utilizando?

Comment: Não sei porque, mas tentei hoje de manhã e funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado @rubStackOverflow, você me ajudou bastante!